# LINQ Determine if a property on an object in a collection exists in a different collection

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a collection of Person objects -

```
public class Person
{
  public string Firstname { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I have a different collection, holding the surnames of the families I've invited to my party -

```
var guestlist = new List<string> {"Stark", "Wayne"};
```

How can I use linq (preferrably lamba based, but this doesn't matter too much) to only pull out members of the Stark or Wayne family? ie. I want to end up with another (third) collection, not just an indication that my first collection contains a Wayne or Stark family member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
var invited = persons.Where(p => guestlist.Contains(p.Surname));
```

Answer (score 2):

This operation, conceptually, is a join.  It's matching objects that "belong" together from two different sets.

```
var query = from person in people
    join name in guestlist 
    on person.Surname equals name
    select person;
```

Note that all of the other solutions that involve using `Contains` on the list of names for each item in the list of people will work when the size of both collections are small, but the solution doesn't scale well at all for larger collections as you are forced to do a linear search *for each item*.  A join, when implemented properly (which LINQ does) will place the guest list into a collection that can be much more efficiently searched.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
var peopleList = GetPeopleList();
var guestList = new List<string> {"Stark", "Wayne"};
var matchList = peopleList.Where(o => guestList.Contains(o));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = people.Where(x => guestlist.Contains(x.Surname));
```